# Gametree not working correctly Java. Is the addChild() function ok?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;


public class Tree 
{
    private Board board;
    private List<Tree> children;
    private Tree parent;

    public Tree(Board board1)
    {
        this.board = board1;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    }
    public Tree(Tree t1)
    {

    }

    public Tree createTree(Tree tree, boolean isHuman, int depth)
    {
        Player play1 = new Player();
        ArrayList<Board> potBoards = new ArrayList<Board>(play1.potentialMoves(tree.board, isHuman));

        if (board.gameEnd() || depth == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Tree oldTree = new Tree(board);

        for (int i = 0; i < potBoards.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            Tree newTree = new Tree(potBoards.get(i));
            createTree(newTree, !isHuman, depth - 1);
            tree.addChild(newTree);
        }

        return tree;
    }

    private Tree addChild(Tree child) 
    {
        Tree childNode = new Tree(child);
        childNode.parent = this;
        this.children.add(childNode);
        return childNode; 
    }
   }
```

Hi there. I'm trying to make a gameTree that will be handled by minimax in the future. I think the error either happened in the AddChild function or the potentialMoves? The potentialMoves returns all potential moves a player or computer can make. For example in Othello a player can either go

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7          
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
0| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
2| | | |b| | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
3| | | |b|b| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
4| | | |b|w| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
5| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
6| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
7| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
0| | | | | | | | |

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
2| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
3| | |b|b|b| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
4| | | |b|w| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
5| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
6| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
7| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
0| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
2| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
3| | | |w|b| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
4| | | |b|b|b| | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
5| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
6| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
7| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
0| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
2| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
3| | | |w|b| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
4| | | |b|b|| | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
5| | | | |b| | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
6| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
7| | | | | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

for the first turn. The potential moves does not permanently change the board that is being played on. It returns an ArrayList.

I have this in my main:

```
Tree gameTree = new Tree(boardOthello);
Tree pickTree = gameTree.createTree(gameTree, true, 2);
```

Does the addChild() function look ok or is there something else I'm missing in my code?